# CSS make background with half height behind content

Tags: html, css

I want to make make div with background, I want to make oeverlay effect in div. This is what I do.
[image: This is what I do]

I want to make it like this
[image: What I want]

```css
body {
  background: blue;
}

.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.background {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ffffff 50%, #e5e5e5 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(.5, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #e5e5e5));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 50%, #e5e5e5 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 50%, #e5e5e5 100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="background">
  <div class="wrap"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might get you started.

You can use `position:absolute;` to remove the `.wrap` div from the HTML flow, allowing you to position it ***relative*** to its parent element (in this case, `.container`)

Note that you must style the `container` div as either `position:relative` or `position:absolute` in order for `position:absolute` to work for the `wrap` div.

```css
body{
 background:blue;
}
.container{position:absolute;height:1000px;}
.background{
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:150px;
 padding:20px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.wrap{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:50px;
 height:250px;
 width:350px;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <section class="background"></section>
    <div class="wrap"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```